# Moq Verify Expression

Tags: c#, moq

Good Day,

I have a class that performs a registry lookup to determine where an application is installed (on a 64-bit machine).

I'm writing a unit test in an attempt to verify that and here's what I have:

```
[Test, Explicit]
public void Validate64Bit()
{
    wsMock.Setup(x => x.IsInstalled).Returns(true);
    wsMock.Setup(x => x.Path).Returns(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\DIRP\");

    IWorkstationLocator workstationLocator = new WorkstationLocator();
    string workstationInstallationPath = workstationLocator.Path;

    Assert.That(workstationInstallationPath != string.Empty, "The install path should exist.");
    wsMock.Verify(x => x.Path == workstationInstallationPath, 
        "64-bit Workstation Install Path should match:  " + @"C:\Program Files (x86)\DIRP\");
    }
```

But I'm getting an error:

System.ArgumentException :  Expression is not a method invocation:
    x => x.Path == .workstationInstallationPath

So my question is:  I want to test if x.Path == wrokstationInstallationPath.

How would I do this in a .Verify() method?

Or am I better off using an Assert?

TIA,

coson

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to use a mock here.

Your *sut* appears to be the `WorkstationLocator` class and all you check is that the `Path` property is equal to a particular value.

You could simply do:

```
[Test, Explicit]
public void Validate64Bit()
{
    var expectedPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\DIRP\";

    IWorkstationLocator workstationLocator = new WorkstationLocator();

    Assert.AreEqual(expectedPath, workstationLocator.Path, 
        "64-bit Workstation Install Path should match:  " + expectedPath);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Moq's `Verify` is typically used to verify that a particular method was called .  For example,

```
// Verify with custom error message for failure
mock.Verify(foo => foo.Execute("ping"), "When doing operation X, the service should be pinged always");
```

If you're testing that x.Path == workstationInstallationPath, you're really just asserting that both values are the same, not verifying that either was set by some sort of method invocation.